# How to use Auth middleware in my own package in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I have created a new package with some custom routes. Within these routes I need to access the Auth::id(). I have wrapped the routes with the usual auth middleware like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

    Route::get('/importer', '\Vendor\Package\Controllers\ImporterController@index');
    Route::post('/importer/import', '\Vendor\Package\Controllers\ImporterController@import');

});
```

When I navigate to any of my routes, I am redirected to /home even whilst logged in.

Do I need to register something in my package to set up the authentication environment?

Comment: What route are you hitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked this out - seems I had to add the web guard to the route group like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function(){

    Route::get('/importer', '\Vendor\Package\Controllers\ImporterController@index');
    Route::post('/importer/import', '\Vendor\Package\Controllers\ImporterController@import');

});
```